# Don't refresh when typing jquery and coldfusion

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a simple page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'test2.cfm',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          //alert('form was submitted');
           $("#alldetails").load('details.cfm?randval='+ Math.random());
          document.myform.tekst.value = "";
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>



</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" name="myform">
  <input type="text" name="text"><br>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<br>

<div id="alldetails">Loading</div>


 <!--- stop when typing comment check and auto refresh --->
 <script>
var isTyping = false;
$("#input-box").focus(function() {
    isTyping = true;
});
$("#input-box").blur(function() {
    isTyping = false;
});


$(document).ready(function() {
$("#alldetails").load("details.cfm");
$(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
  if (!isTyping) {
  $("#alldetails").load('details.cfm?randval='+ Math.random());
  }}, 20000);
   });

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
   });
   </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the details are loaded in the div (allDetails) and that is working fine so far. Now on my details.cfm page I'm showing the messages and people can react on them. So far so good, but what I want to do is stop the autorefresh when some is typing a comment. I have try this, see the comment in the code above 'stop when typing and auto rerfesh'. Because the comment input field is on the comment.cfm page, it is ignoring this script.

Hope you understand the question.

Regards!

Edit:

the code of details.cfm:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#testform').on('submit', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'save_comment.cfm',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>

<cfquery datasource="#ns#" name="getdata">
select text, timeline_id
from timeline
order by t_datum desc
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="getdata">
<p>#tekst#</p>
<cfform id="testform">
<cfinput type="hidden" value="#timeline_id#" name="timeline_id"> 
<cfinput type="text" name="comment#timeline_id#" id="input-box"><input type="submit">
</cfform>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: If you are using AJAX there is no need to auto-refresh the page. Use AJAX to populate the information instead of auto-refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

use angular and ng-model its an easier way to do the data binding, or you can remove the setInterval and use **setTimeout()** the time out function will be instantiated then when the timer runs out it will execute the code your **setInterval** will continually loop through the code without stopping, thats why you are getting the refresh constantly happening you should bind the setTimeout to the key up event that way you will have a little more control over when then events fire. setInterval is a loop that does not stop, setTimeout does not loop it will only fire once unless its re-instantiated.